# How to make a form-filling google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if anyone could provide me with some links to some tutorials or explain (with some example code), how I would go about making a simple google chrome extension (or in any programming language or browser if that is impossible), how I would make an extension that can visit a specific site, fill a login form on that site, click some links and then do the same sort of thing on the linked to site.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally, I would not use a chrome extension, but maybe a perl script. There is an extension called [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) that is designed exactly to do this kind of stuff.

You can find plenty of tutorials and examples, just google it.

---

*Edit in 2021*: the above recommendation has become a bit outdated since 2013. For a more up-to-date take, I'd still recommend a scriptable headless browser instead of an extension for most automation tasks, but probably not WWW:Mechanize. There are good lists of options, such as [this one](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

Comment: I agree with @TMicheal but will you explain is there any particular reason not to use chrome extension and perl script ?

Comment: I think writing a script  for the above purpose may be a better choice because the result is 1) lightweight 2) easy to run (even from a terminal-only environment) 3) can easily be integrated with other scripts / software if needed. The arguments for a chrome extension on the other hand would be 1) you may be more familiar with javascript 2) some websites require a real browser 3) you may have to interact manually at certain points. The second one is easily solved using WWW::Mechanize::{Firefox,Chrome or PhantomJS} though.